# Clarification about OOP in php

Tags: php, oop

Few of my friend said that traditional way of programming can conflict. For an Example I have created and input box and submit button like this

```
    <form name="sample" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    echo $name;}
?>
```

Now there if three user example tom,jerry and spike enter them name and press submit at the same time is the result can conflict?
I have also heard that writing on OOP dose not conflicts. Is it true? If I have to write the same program in OOP the how it will be?
Thanks,

Comment: What you heard may be true, but definitely not on this context. Your result won't get mixed by simply echoing a post variable.

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense - what are you expecting to conflict?  It isn't like they made PHP with a non-object oriented mode that just fundamentally doesn't work...

Comment: Why unaccep my awnser, when its the same as the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned, three people submitting a form at the same time will not cause a conflict with what you are doing - simply echoing the inputted value. The way PHP works is to give Tom, Jerry, and Spike each their own `$name`.

As for an object-oriented approach, the final approach would depend on the scope of your project.

```
class Person
{
    private $_name;

    public function __construct( $name )
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    public function WhoAmI()
    {
        echo $this->_name;
    }
}

$myPerson = new Person( $_POST['name'] );
$myPerson->WhoAmI();
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't conflict with other users, since every user has his own "Session". OOP is used to make specific classes to make handling a specific object easier.

Example if you have multiple users it might be easier to use an OOP class.

```
class User {

  $name;

  function __construct( $name ) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }

}
```

I would really recommend to look at this url: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: "instance" is perhaps less confusing than "session" in this context. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

What you've heard is nonsensical and wrong. Variables are not shared between invocations of a PHP script; multiple users accessing this script at once would not see inconsistent results.

There is absolutely no difference between OOP and non-OOP PHP programming in this regard.